# MVVM binding ObservableCollection to Listview Not working

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am new to MVVM, I am trying to bind ObservableCollection to Listview.

ViewModel

```
namespace Multiwindow.Viewmodel
{

    public class ViewModelBase
    {
        public Commandclass Cclass { get; set; }

        private ObservableCollection<Person> observableprsn = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        public ViewModelBase()
        {
            Cclass = new Commandclass(this);
        }

        public void oncommand()
        {   
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Person p = new Person();
                p.Name = "name";
                p.Lastname = "lastname" + i;
                observableprsn.Add(p);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <m:Person x:Key="personmodel"/>
        <vm:ViewModelBase x:Key="vmodel"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Background="Gray" DataContext="{StaticResource vmodel}">

            <Button Content="Load Window 2" Margin="155,108,177,157"
                    Command="{Binding Cclass, Source={StaticResource vmodel}}" />

            <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Width="184" 
                      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource vmodel}}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding }">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Address"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Lastname}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>

        </Grid>
```

On button click i am binding to listview some data in loop of class person with propert Name and Lastname, where am i Wrong. thanks

Comment: Why `ItemsSource="{Binding }">` is left empty should it be `observableprsn`

Comment: Is there any binding errors in you application, please see output for binding errors

Comment: No error, I have tried ItemsSource="{Binding observableprsn }"> but no impact.

Comment: Is the command in `Vm` is invoked

Comment: Yes the oncommand is invoked. From ICommand interface

Comment: your `observable Collection` should be `public`

Comment: I tried public no imact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109125/discussion-between-eldho-and-shiv).

Comment: Change your xaml too, i have updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> observableprsn = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

> Instead of private property you need a `Public` Collection

```
   public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return _observableprsn; }
        set
        {
            if (_observableprsn != value)
            {
                _observableprsn = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _observableprsn { get; set; }
```

Xaml (This works for me)

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Width="184" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Address"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding lastName}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any property that you would like to bind in your view should be either a [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) or implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). These properties should be **public** so that they are accessable by the view.

Implement your ViewModel like this:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _observableprsn = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return _observableprsn; }
        set
        {
            if (_observableprsn != value)
            {
                _observableprsn = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Persons);
            }
        }
    }

    #region implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocatorAttribute]
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        var propertyName = ExtractPropertyName(propertyExpression);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private static string ExtractPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        if (propertyExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");
        }

        var memberExpression = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The expression is not a member access expression.", "propertyExpression");
        }

        var property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The member access expression does not access a property.", "propertyExpression");
        }

        var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(true);
        if (getMethod.IsStatic)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The referenced property is a static property.", "propertyExpression");
        }

        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The Person class should of course also either implement [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) or [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I think `ObservableCollection` will raise `collectionChanged event` when `Add` or `Remove` Is occured, Only we need to `RaiseProperty` when property is changed. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Correct. However, when a property of Person is changed (e.g. Name) this will not be reflected in the View unless the Person class fires its own PropertyChanged event.

Comment: In OP its `Add()` is been invoked so suppose to be updated automatically

Comment: @Eldho. Indeed, the Add() method will cause the ObservableCollection to fire the CollectionChanged event.

Comment: Yes, so i assuming the RaiseProperty is not what causing the issue